# SQL order by string + integers

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

How can I ORDER BY a string which has ID at the end of the string?

For Example, I want to order these Strings by the numbers at the end (after RSPP):

```
RSPP891
RSPP896
RSPP897
RSPP898
RSPP899
RSPP900
RSPP901
RSPP902
RSPP903
RSPP904
RSPP730
RSPP731
RSPP1380
RSPP733
RSPP734
```

I read something about substringing so i tried this query instead, but without any success.

```
SELECT `RsppTags` FROM Table WHERE ConnectionID = 15202  
ORDER BY
SUBSTR(RsppTags FROM 4 FOR LENGTH(RsppTags)-1),
CAST(SUBSTR(RsppTags FROM 1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Is it possible to get this data `ORDER BY ASC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(RsppTags FROM 5) AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle showing the result](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c41d877/3)

Comment: @SagarGangwal It is not as ASC is the default sort order, but I included the keyword to be explicit, which I feel can be helpful as it doesn't assume prior knowledge about how the DB engine sorts by default.

Answer (score 2):

**`SELECT RsppTags FROM Table 
 WHERE ConnectionID = 15202
 ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(RsppTags FROM 5) AS UNSIGNED)`**

By default MYSQL provide ASC ordering.

Try above query.
It will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
order by SUBSTR(RsppTags, 5) + 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT `RsppTags` FROM Table WHERE ConnectionID = 15202  
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(RsppTags, 5) AS UNSIGNED) ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `RsppTags` 
FROM Table WHERE ConnectionID = 15202  
ORDER BY
SUBSTR(RsppTags,1,4), 
CAST(SUBSTR(RsppTags,5) AS UNSIGNED);
```